# Docker - I fail to display my container on browser

Tags: docker

I can't figure out why I can't display my containers in my browser.

I want to run a jenkins image.
When I enter docker ps it returns me:

> a7adea029d28        jenkins/jenkins:lts   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   15
>   minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp,
>   50000/tcp   test_server

If I enter `localhost:5000` it fails, if I enter  `192.168.99.100:5000` it fails, the same if I try `8080` as port coordinates. 
I don't know what to do and can't figure out why it fails.

I have tried on firefox also and it fails too,

if someone has any hint, would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts` to create the container. After this you should be able to access Jenkins on port 8080.

Although the port 8080 is available on your current container is not being forwarded to the docker machine.

Comment: Purely awesome, can you explain us what just happened please ? I'm feeling like I have missed something very now

Comment: Yeah. It seems like you forgot the `... -p 8080:8080 ...` part when creating the test_server container. @Webman

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `-P`(capital letter) flag in docker run command as shown below:

`docker run -it -P IMAGE_NAME`

It is different from `-p`(small letter) flag because in this you don't specify the host port to which you want to map the container port. It automatically maps the host port to the container port. You can see which host port has been mapped using `docker port CONTAINER_ID`

Comment: (Only ports that are explicitly EXPOSEd in the Dockerfile, but conversely this is pretty much the only case where EXPOSE has an effect.)